# Search with "And" operator in Elastic search PHP package

Tags: php, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-php

I'm trying to learn `Elastic Search` with help of php composer package. I'm having a `index` with the name of `media_data` which contains `nits_account`, `nits_url`, `session_id`, `timestamp` fields. I want to have filters based on above fields and it should be in `and` operator. my current query code is:

```
$items = $this->elasticsearch->search([
    'index' => $index_name,
    'body'  => [
        'query' => [
            'filtered' => [
                'filter' => [
                    'and' => [
                        ['match' => ['nits_account' => 'xyzABCD2190-aldsj']],  //API Key
                        ['match' => ['nits_url' => 'google.com']],
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]);
```

My question:

1. I'm unable to fetch data. But if I do below code:

   ```
   $items = $this->elasticsearch->search([
       'index' => $index_name,
       'body'  => [
           'query' => [
                'bool' => [
                   'should' => [
                       ['match' => ['nits_account' => $account] ],
                       ['match' => ['nits_url' => $domain] ],
                   ],
               ], 
           ]
       ]
   ]);
   ```

I get values in `or` operators, but need to have `and` operation in it.

2. How can I have different search operations with respective fields, I mean I want to have `nits_account` field to be exact match, I want to have `nits_url` with like/wildcard operations, timestamp should be comparable (greater than/less than/between two dates).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$items = $this->elasticsearch->search([
    'index' => $index_name,
    'body'  => [
        'query' => [
             'bool' => [
                'must' => [
                    ['match' => ['nits_account' => $account] ],
                    ['match' => ['nits_url' => $domain] ]
                ],
            ], 
        ]
    ]
]);
```

You should use `must` keyword, not `should` keyword. `must` acts like **AND** operation while `should` acts like **OR** operation.

See this https://stackoverflow.com/a/28768600/5430055

if you need to use conditional match use something like this:

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "nits_url": {
              "gte": 1000,
              "lte": 10000
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "nits_account": "$account"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks it helped me, I got stuck with minus (-) sign in my strings, I went through lot of docs then I got to know that we have to have analyzers defined to query over special characters. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44043372/match-string-with-minus-character-in-elasticsearch Hope it helps someone